# How to make a image processing to use all CPU core

Tags: multithreading, image, java-8, image-segmentation, java-threads

I need a function how is capable to build an image based on multiple merges. So I do this

```
public static void mergeImagesByName(List<String> names) {
File folder;
File[] listOfFiles;
List<String> allFilesName;

folder = new File("images/");
listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

allFilesName = new ArrayList<>();
for (File fileName : listOfFiles) {
    allFilesName.add(fileName.getName());
}

List<String> imgName = names.stream().map(name -> name += ".PNG").collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> allExistingName = new ArrayList<>();

allFilesName.stream().forEach((file) -> imgName.stream().filter((name) -> (file.equals(name))).forEach((name) -> allExistingName.add(name)));
try {
    File baseImage = new File(folder, "MERGE.PNG");
    BufferedImage textImage = ImageIO.read(new File(folder, "Text.PNG"));
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(baseImage);
    int w = 800;
    int h = 450;
    BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics g = combined.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

    for (String name : allExistingName) {
        BufferedImage overlay = ImageIO.read(new File(folder, name));
        g.drawImage(overlay, 0, 0, null);
        ImageIO.write(combined, "PNG", new File(folder, "MERGE.PNG"));
    }
    g.drawImage(textImage, 0, 0, null);

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MergeImages.class
            .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

}
But it's to slower for what I need... I need almost 5-8sec to execute all my images and create the result. So I'm thinking... if I will make it to run on multiple core simultaneous that will increase my speed. For example.. I've 4 core, if I will can to divide my original list of elements in 4 list and with of them will have just a quarter part or original list, these can run each of them on one core, and after all will finished I can to merge just 4 images on one. But I have no idea how to do that... So please guys, if anyone of you know how to do that please show me :D

Thx and sorry for me bad English.

Comment: Which part do you not have any idea how to do; all of it? Are you able to partition the list by establishing indices?

Comment: I have no idea how to use threads to do that... I've search on internet allot... But I've don't find any solution about how to do that with threads..

Comment: You don't need to use threads to partition the list. You'd want to do that before creating the four threads. Then you'd pass a reference to the shared list and the indices that thread is responsible for. You probably have more than one question here because as is it's too broad.

Comment: If you add `parallel()` to your `allFilesName ` stream then it will process it across threads for you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this type of application, but is it necessary to write the `MERGE.PNG` file on every iteration? Can you just apply each overlay in memory in the loop and then write the file when all of the overlays are applied?

Answer (score 0):

The solve was really simple, I need just to use parallelStream and all work much fasted

```
allExistingName.parallelStream().forEach(name -> {
    BufferedImage overlay = images.get(name);
    g.drawImage(overlay, 0, 0, null);
});
ImageIO.write(combined, "PNG", new File(folder, "MERGE.PNG"));
```

That was all what I need